# File Not Saved in Server - Quartz.Net

Tags: c#, quartz.net

I have created a CronJob Using Quartz.Net Version 2.5.0. The Purpose of this CronJob

1. Has to run daily at a particular time.
2. Download file from FTP location and save it in local.
3. Process the downloaded file.

Have used below code to download the file from the FTP Location

```
            FtpWebRequest request = 
            (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(objSettings.FTPHostName + 
             "//" + objSettings.FileName);
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
            request.Credentials = new 
            NetworkCredential(objSettings.FTPUserName, 
            objSettings.FTPPassword);
            FtpWebResponse response = 
            (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            FileStream file = File.Create(outputFileNameWithPath);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[32 * 1024];
            int read;

            while ((read = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) 
            > 0)
            {
                file.Write(buffer, 0, read);
            }

            file.Close();
            responseStream.Close();
            response.Close();
```

The Variable outputFileNameWithPath will have File Name with Path. (Ex. C:\Services\11-04-2019\VENDORNAME\invlistcsv.csv)

Have tested this CronJob in my local environment, the CronJob runs at a particular time, downloads the file from FTP location and save it in local  and process the downloaded file.

I also verified whether the downloaded file is available in local and its available under C:\Services\ Folder.

I then configured the CronJob in server. The CronJob runs without any errors, the problem i am facing here is the download files by the CronJob Service are not available in folder C:\Services in server.

Have also verified whether the folder is having full permission and also the Logs. The Log clearly says that the CronJob have downloaded the file and the File is available in this location and also the Cronjob has processed the downloaded file.But the file is not available.

Not sure what is causing this ISSUE. Please guide me on fixing this issue.

Comment: I would check real value of the variable outputFileNameWithPath, for example writing it to log. And then value of File.Exists(outputFileNameWithPath).

Comment: Grzesiek Danowski  Thanks for you reply. Have Logged the variable outputFileNameWithPath and File.Exists(outputFileNameWithPath) information.

Comment: On analyzing the log for couple of days.. have found where the issue was. Thanks Grzesiek Danowski for your suggestion.